# Missing The Mysql Extension of wordpress in cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I go through your last post but my problem is little different. 
I recently upload my wordpress site and then i upload my theme. After that i install demo of that theme and also install its plugin one by one. For one week it is running smooth and fast. After one week i get an error

**Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which
is required by WordPress.**

Then i try to reinstall my WordPress setup and also try to install database but the error not change.

Even i goto phpmyadmin and then there i saw the version and the mysqli. there it is telling that my php is latest and all is ok then why the hell giving me this kind of error.

[phpmyadmin pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOIjN.png)
I am giving you my phpmyadmin pic which tells the version

Comment: is phpmyadmin and the wordpress site running on the same server?

Comment: yes same server... same site

Answer (score 0):

Your website have available wordfence plugin?
If its not then follow below link for solution.
https://bobcares.com/blog/fix-wordpress-error-php-installation-missing-mysql-extension/

Comment: i also visit this site... i m working on a online server and update a wordpress setup but problem remain same

Comment: Your website have available wordfence plugin?